# No compatible source was found for this video in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, safari

I see this error "No compatible source was found for this video." over the video in safari. I am using video.js for displaying videos. And here is html for one of my videos which isn't working on safari:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="true" preload="yes" width="640" height="380" poster="poster.jpg" data-setup="{}" src="video.mp4">
    <source src="video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: safari will choose the mp4. So there is something wrong with the mp4. Does it use unsupported codecs? was fast start run on the file? can you link to the file or at least `mediainfo` output?

Comment: What you mean 'Does it use unsupported codecs' @szatmary

Comment: mp4 is just the container type. It supports dozens of codecs. You browser will only support a handful of codecs.

Comment: how can I know that it uses unsupported codecs pls? @szatmary

Comment: check the file to see what codec it is using. VLC media info window will tell you this. Then see if the codec is supported in safari.

Comment: I checked it shows this "Format: AVC, Format/Info                            Advanced Video Codec, Format profile : High@L3.0Format settings, CABAC: No, Format settings, ReFrames  : 1 frame, Codec ID                                : avc1, Codec ID/Info: Advanced Video Coding" @szatmary